# Jogando mais de um campo txt dentro do banco de dados

Tags: php

Colegas.

Estou querendo pegar os dados de um arquivo txt que contém o nome e matrícula do usuário. Ex.:

```
Fernando Pessoa; 000011;
Ruth Cardoso; 000012;
....
```

Ao tentar pegar dessa forma:

```
    $diretorio = 'arquivos/';
    $arquivos = $diretorio . $_FILES['dados']['name'];

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['dados']['tmp_name'], $diretorio . $_FILES['dados']['name'])) {
            $ler = fopen($arquivos,"r");
            $conteudo = fread($ler,filesize($arquivos));
            $dividir = explode(";",$conteudo);

              foreach($dividir as $valores){
                   echo $dividir[0]." => ".$dividir[1]."<br>";
                   // aqui faço o cadastro
           }
    }
```

Ele retorna apenas o primeiro nome e matrícula repetindo conforme a quantidade total de dados cadastrados no txt. Se tiver 30 nomes e matrículas, está trazendo 30 vezes Fernando Pessoa 000011 e nao os outros dados

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem dois pontos onde está a falhar:

1. O explode primeiro teria de ser por quebra de linha (\n), e só depois por ';'
2. dentro do seu `foreach` está sempre a fazer echo dos mesmos dados (`$dividir[0]`, `$dividir[1]`)

Versão correta:

```
...
$dividir = explode("\n",$conteudo);
foreach($dividir as $valores){
    $exp = explode(';', $valores);
    if(isset($exp[1])) {
        echo $exp[0]. " => ".$exp[1]."<br>";
        // aqui faço o cadastro
    }
}
fclose($ler);
```

Comment: Perfeito Miguel. Funcionou. Obrigado !

Comment: @Fox.11 Depois de ler o arquivo feche o *handle* com `fclose($ler)`.

Comment: De nada @Fox.11. Ainda bem

Comment: @zekk, obgado vou editar de acordo, esqueci-me

Answer (score 0):

Isso acontece porque você está acessando um valor fixo do `array` e não o elemento atual da iteração.

Altere: `$dividir[0]` e `$dividir[1]` por `$valores[0]` e `$valores[1]`.

O modo de como fazer isto já foi explicado na [resposta do Miguel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/143675/6454), segue abaixo outra alternativa:

```
$diretorio = 'arquivos/';
$arquivo = $diretorio . $_FILES['dados']['name'];

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['dados']['tmp_name'], $arquivo)) {
  $conteudo = file_get_contents($arquivo);
  $linhas = explode("\n", $conteudo);

  foreach($linhas as $linha){
     if (empty($linha)){
       continue;
     }
  list($nome, $id) = array_map('trim', explode(";", $linha));

  echo "Nome: $nome - Matrícula: $id\n";
  // Fazer o cadastro...
}
```

- É usado o [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-get-contents.php) ao invés do `fopen()` para lidar com o arquivo.
- A função [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.trim.php) é para eliminar o espaço em branco entre o separador `;` e os números.